# Copy lines from a File to another

Tags: java, file, filereader

I need to copy a line from a file to another depending on condition
this is my code

```
     import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

     public class FileCopy {

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException { 

    File source = \\
    File fileToCopyFrom \\
    File target :\\
    if (!target.exists()) {
        target.createNewFile();
    }

    PrintStream fstream =new PrintStream(target);
    BufferedReader brSource = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(source));
    BufferedReader brFileToCopyFrom = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileToCopyFrom));

    String lineSource;
    String lineToCopy;

    while((lineSource = brSource.readLine()) != null) {

          while ((lineToCopy=brFileToCopyFrom.readLine())!=null) {
    if (lineToCopy.contains(lineSource.substring(lineSource.indexOf("_")+1, lineSource.indexOf(".")-1)))
                fstream.println(lineToCopy);    
            }

        }
}}
```

but it copy only the first line 
where is the error?

Comment: what error do you have?

Comment: it copy only one line

Comment: it looks right to me, is it possible there is something wrong with your is statement? can you attached your files as well?

Comment: check EDIT section in My anwser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the first is copied because in the second iteration of the first `while` the `brFileToCopyFrom` is reached the end of file.

You need to open the `BufferedReader brFileToCopy` inside the first `while` (example 1) or use a `mark/reset` feature (example 2).

Example 1:

```
while ((lineSource = brSource.readLine()) != null) {

        BufferedReader brFileToCopyFrom = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileToCopyFrom));

        while ((lineToCopy = brFileToCopyFrom.readLine()) != null) {
            ...
        }

    }
}
```

Example 2:

```
brFileToCopyFrom.mark(1024); // number of characters to be read while preserving the mark

while ((lineSource = brSource.readLine()) != null) {

        brFileToCopyFrom.reset();

        while ((lineToCopy = brFileToCopyFrom.readLine()) != null) {
            ...
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: The stream somehow remembers all the bytes read after the call to mark and stands ready to supply those same bytes again if and whenever the method reset is called.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use `commons-io.jar`. In this `FileUtils` class lot of methods to do `File` operation like copy, move and remove.

**EDIT**

try with below if conndition which contains `break`.

```
while ((lineSource = brSource.readLine()) != null) {

            while ((lineToCopy = brFileToCopyFrom.readLine()) != null) {
                if (lineToCopy.contains(lineSource.substring(
                        lineSource.indexOf("_") + 1,
                        lineSource.indexOf(".") - 1))) {
                    fstream.println(lineToCopy);
                    break;
                }
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you create your stream, you read all enntries from your stream, for first line, but when you want to do this for second line brFileToCopyFrom is empty (you already took everything from it when you were checking your first line.

so what you could do is move creating your `brFileToCopyFrom` to the loop,

```
while((lineSource = brSource.readLine()) != null) {
BufferedReader brFileToCopyFrom = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileToCopyFrom));

...
```

that should works